# Using full text search in PostgreSQL, how can I make certain words worth less to match?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use Postgres full-text search to search an index of company names.  There are lots of duplicates, typos, etc.  When matching company names, things like *LLC* and *Inc* are not quite stop-words (as in, I want them to count for something) but they are not nearly as important as most other words.  Is there a way to query such that some words count more than other words when matching?

(I'm doing this all through Django, but if I can figure out the SQL to use I can probably get the rest of the way there...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [3-argument form of "setweight"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) to de-weight specific lexemes.  You would do this in the tsvector, not in the tsquery.

```
select setweight(setweight(to_tsvector('The DBA LLC'),'A'),'D','{llc}');
     setweight     
-------------------
 'dba':2A 'llc':3D
```